# How to extract monthly financial time series given daily fts

Tags: matlab

I understand that we can use the function 'tomonthly' within the financial toolbox but this returns a default monthly data taking the last business day of every month.

What if i want the first business day of every month instead?

I have tried using 'ED' set to 1 in the following manner:

```
ftsFuture = fints (matlabDate, lnPrice);
monthlyFuture = tomonthly(ftsFuture,'ED',1);
```

But this was only partially successful in the sense that if the 1st of the month is a working day, it is alright, but if it is not a working day, it becomes the previous working day, which is in the previous month.

I have also tried using 'BusDays' by setting it to 0, in the following manner:

```
ftsFuture = fints (matlabDate, lnPrice);
monthlyFuture = tomonthly(ftsFuture,'ED',1, 'BusDays',0);
```

This successfully forces every entry to be the 1st of each month but clearly cannot be correct as some of these dates are clearly not working days!

Any help with this is vastly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to extract the data from daily financial time series in monthly periods starting on the first business day of the month. We can get dates in the middle of the series using `tomonthly` and `busdate` functions.

Assuming the data starts at the beginning of some month and ends at the end certain month, we add the first date and eliminate the last date we will get after the operations.

```
ftsFuture = fints (matlabDate, lnPrice);
monthlyFuture = tomonthly(ftsFuture);
eomDates = monthlyFuture.dates ; % getting end of month business days) 
fomDates = busdate(eomDates) ;  % getting first month bussines days)
fomDates(end)=[] ; % deleting the last date in the array (out of range otherwise).
firstday = ftsFuture.dates(1); % adding the first date of the series.
fomDates = [firstday ; fomDates];
fomDates = datestr(fomDates);
fomftsFuture = ftsFuture(fomDates);
```